# htaccess rewrite slug in a url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've searched and searched for help on a rewrite rule but nothing seems to match specifically what I'm trying to do, hopefully someone can help?

I'm trying to replace a slug in a url that could have various other possible slugs before and after it.

e.g.

```
http://www.example.com/slug/old_slug
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/slug/new_slug
```

or

```
/slug/old_slug/slug
```

to

```
/slug/new_slug/slug
```

or

```
/slug/old_slug/slug/slug
```

to

```
/slug/new_slug/slug/slug
```

or finally:

```
/slug/old_slug/slug?param=1&param=2
```

to

```
/slug/new_slug/slug?param=1&param=2
```

If that sounds confusing these are products in categories with various possible url parameters after them and I'm having to rename a product that means I want to rewrite the old urls for SEO and inbound links.

Comment: Is `/slug` a static text or some dynamic value?

Comment: dynamic, so it might be /dishwasher/ or /microwave/ etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/old_slug(/.*)?$ /$1/new_slug$2 [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you. a friend also suggested this which seems to do the trick as well.... rewriterule ^(.*)old_slug(.*)$ /$1new_slug$2 [L,R=301,QSA]

Comment: No use my suggested rule above as that rule will also match `/slug/bold_slugs/` which won't be the case with my answer above.