# how to do 301 redirect using .htaccess, after changing custom post type slug

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I need help regarding 301 redirects after changing custom post type slug, for example  - I have changed custom post type slug "portfolio_page" to "portfolio-page" in the funcation.php using the rewrite tag, now I want to redirect all the post that have "portfolio_page/post-name" slug to "portfolio-page/post-name".

Thanks

Comment: After change post type slug have you do update permalink from Settings >> Permalink

Comment: can you paste the complete code for register custom post type

Answer (score 0):

If the change to your custom post type works (f.e. the pages are accessible on /portfolio-page/post-name) and you only want to redirect the /portfolio_page/post-name to /portfolio-page/post-name for, let's say, make visitors to the old URL go to the new: read: [htaccess rewrite slug in a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127863/htaccess-rewrite-slug-in-a-url)

If you don not have access to your .htaccess, you can also use the redirection plugin available for wordpress, see: https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/